# Is it possible to post a message to Skype chat from an external client (e.g. Postman)?

Tags: postman, skype, skype-for-business

I am trying to find a way to deliver a message to Skype chat via http, e.g. using [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or a Java Lib and so far I was not successful. For example, [Microsoft Teams](https://products.office.com/en-us/microsoft-teams/group-chat-software) provides [webhooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) which enables me to send a message to a team from a client such as Postman, therefore I was wondering if there is something like this for Skype.

Thank you for your help.